# How do I get the base URL of my current location?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to get the base URL of my current location however, I have 2 scenarios.

1. http://localhost:6111/Page.aspx
   Base URL: localhost:6111
2. http://localhost/myApp/Page.aspx
   Base URL: localhost/myApp

Am hoping to be able to have one solution to retrieve both base URL. 
Do you all have any recommendation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do

get the whole path but then exclude the file part

```
let absUrl = $location.absUrl();
let expected = absUrl.replace('Page.aspx', '');
```

or if the file name is not the same all the time

```
let expected = absUrl.replace(/([a-z]+\.[a-z]+)/i, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first case you can do this (as [$location API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#host) suggest):

```
// url -> http://localhost:6111/Page.aspx
let host = $location.host();
// host => localhost:6111
```

For the second case I think you need to use both **$location.host()** and **$location.url()**. Then manipulate url to get only first part.

```
// url -> http://localhost/myApp/Page.aspx
let host = $location.host(); // localhost
let url = $location.url(); // /myApp/Page.aspx
let splittedUrl = url.split('/'); // ["", "myApp", "Page.aspx"]
let resultBaseUrl = host + "/" + splittedUrl[1]; // localhost/myApp
```

I'm not completely sure for the second solution, test it and give me a feedback!